# Is there a way to numerically position sun in sky texture?

Tags: light

I'm creating a scene set in a real-world location and require the sun to be at exact locations for the day, however, I can't seem to find a way to precisely control the sky texture's sun position. Is this possible with nodes or anything?

Comment: There is an add-on called geographical sun. That might do the trick, it was in the contrib addons for 2.78rc I think. Not sure of a link off hand.

Comment: You could setup drivers for sky texture, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32894/setting-sun-direction-on-sky-texture-with-an-empty

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it can help you anymore, but I recently found this Addon. 
It sets the Sun according to the geographical position of your model, day and month of the year, time of the day, and Utc zone!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAJeML3A60I&t=87s