# How to drive the normal node with an empty?

Tags: light, shaders

[image: Vector to orient normal node]

Hi, I´ve followed this: [How to correctly drive a normal node with lamp rotation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10560/how-to-correctly-drive-a-normal-node-with-lamp-rotation)

I´ve tried the same setup but I need an empty to drive the direction of the mapping node onto the normal shading.
I think the problem is on the curve drive. What I need is to **translate** the empty on world space and the mapping node will update the normal node as if it was the "light" direction. Please help.

Comment: Also is this question related to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47175/i-want-to-mix-cycles-shaders-based-on-self-shadow

Answer (score 1):

I propose a similar setting, but where the normal is driven by a vector defined by the difference between the empty location and the rendered point location (that could be whole sphere location instead).

Here is opposite views when the empty is moving:

[image]

Here is the material setup:

[image]

- The driver is set on the location vector of a mapping (with no input)
- From that there is the calculation of the difference between the driven values and the rendered location
- The output is normalized and plugged as normal vector

Each driven axis is defined this way, respectively for X, Y and Z:

[image]

[image]

Comment: This setup will not work for other objects surrounding the empty. Their light directions are all dislocated.